# Fourier Expansion of Eisenstein series with half integer weight > 2

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

In "Harmonic Maass Forms and Mock Modular Forms: Theory and Applications" by Bringmann et. al. the Eisenstein-series for half integer weights k>2 are defined as:

\begin{align*}
E_{k,N}(\tau):= \sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma_{\infty} \backslash \Gamma_0(N)} (1|_k \gamma)(\tau),
\end{align*}
for $\tau \in \mathbb{H},$ the upper halfplane. The slash operator is the usual slash operator for integer $k$ and for $k \in \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{Z} \setminus \mathbb{Z} $ it is defined as:
\begin{align*}
f|_k \gamma := \left( \frac{c}{d} \right) \epsilon_d^{2k}(c\tau+d)^{-k}f(\gamma \tau),
\end{align*}
with $ \gamma = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix} $ and $\epsilon_d :=    \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1 & d = 1 \hspace{0.1cm} (mod \hspace{0.1cm} 4) \\
      i & d=3\hspace{0.1cm}  (mod \hspace{0.1cm} 4)  \\
\end{array} 
\right. $.

In Theorem 6.15 the Fourier expansions of $E_{k,N}$ for $k>2$ is used but to my understanding it is not derived anywhere. I know about the Fourier expansion for integer $k>2$ and $N=1$ but got stuck on the $k \in \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{Z} \setminus \mathbb{Z} $ case.   Can anyone point me to a resource where it is derived or explain the process?

I think that the problem can be boiled down to finding the Fourier expansion of
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{\tau + n}\right)^k. 
\end{align*}
Any advice for this would also be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.